# Using an Induction Heater to melt multiple types of metal

Tags: induction, resonance

Right, here's some context. I have a large amount of metal shavings from a dozen different sources, and they are very light and sharp. Some of them aren't, but most of them are. I need to dispose of them without ruining the day of an unlucky employee at a recycling plant. So I intend to melt them into easily organized and transportable ingots.

The only problem is, I also want to learn how to make an induction heater, and all of those metal shavings sound like perfect test subject for this project.

Now, when it comes to making an induction heater, my research has informed me that I need a Tank Capacitor hooked up to an oscillating power supply. The Tank Capacitor part sounds simple enough, I have serviceable capacitors for days, and I have copper pipe from a plumbing project that went nowhere, for the work coil.

The project got complicated when the concept of resonance got introduced. A quick wiki-crawl and an examination of several similar projects revealed that a Tank Capacitor has a specific resonance frequency, where the energy gain (Transfer? Whatever.) is at it's most efficient. The equation can be found with a quick google. However, the inductance, one of the variables used to determine the resonance frequency, changes based on the contents of the work coil. I have been led to believe that it also changes based on how hot the work piece is.

So I have to ask, how do I determine the resonant frequency while the work coil is functioning? Can I just attach a wire to the Tank Capacitor to determine the frequency that its oscillating at, and get the resonant frequency from that?

Comment: employees at a recycling plant already expect everything to be sharp. i do not think that you will surprise them.

Comment: It's less about cutting someone, and more about being impossible to organize if they cut their way out of the bags.

Comment: Many induction heaters use 6 turns of 6 awg solid wire (coil) and several kilowatts of HF pulses (50 KHZ-500 KHZ) driven by expensive MOSFET or IGBT modules. Do you know what your getting into?

Comment: Nope, but I'd like to find out. I don't plan on using more then a kilowatt of power. As for expensive MOSFET/IGBT modules... well, I have a lot of little cheap ones?

Comment: Because of the complexity involved it is best to search the web for "induction heaters". You will find plenty of off-the-shelf units, from 1 KW to 50KW. This question is too broad for us to answer in one page.

Comment: How do I narrow it down? The main focus of this question is determining the resonance frequency of a tank capacitor without knowing the inductance. Is it a phrasing problem? Did I waffle on to long before stating the question?

Comment: The inductance & capacitance *together* form a resonant 'tank circuit'. A 'Tank Capacitor' isn't really a thing, and doesn't really have a resonant frequency of its own (at least not one relevant to what you're trying to do).

Comment: You can just assemble your work coil and capacitor, and stimulate them with a step function, then see what frequency they resonate at. The easiest way to do the step function would be to connect a small battery (like a 9V transistor battery), then remove it and watch the sine wave with an oscilloscope. You can do this with and without metal in the coil. You are not going to be actually heating up the work piece. Just observing the frequency. It doesn't matter that it is a low voltage.

Comment: From videos I have seen online, the capacitors tend to get hot, because the resonant current is pretty high.

Comment: Having large unknown alloy chunks will ruin his day more than shavings that he can sort if he wants

Comment: PlasmaHH- I have already sorted them out. I can label the ingots easier than the shavings. mkeith- I can keep the capacitors cool enough to work. The problem with that is that I've been informed that the resonant frequency changes as the temperature of the metal rises. I need to know how to track that. brhans- My research told me that the terms "Tank Circuit" and "Tank Capacitor" were interchangeable. My research has lied to me.

Comment: I think the change with temperature you are talking about occurs with iron and steel when the metal is heated beyond the curie point. What happens is that the magnetic properties of the steel change, so the coil inductance decreases markedly. You can just hand tune the frequency and monitor total power output. At resonance, the output of the DC supply will be maximum. With other metals, this will likely not be a big problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking how to measure the frequency once you've already gotten it oscillating. That's much easier than getting the circuit oscillating properly in the first place, but so be it.  I would recommend a small pickup coil a safe distance from your heating coil.  Send it to your counter or oscilloscope and you should see a nice signal.  Now for dimensions, I'd take a guess that at 1 MHz and with a 5 kW heating power you'd probably want a coil area of about 1 cm squared and about 10 turns.  Insulate it so you can't burn out your counter/scope if something goes wrong.

Comment: Wait, so the Tank Circuit always oscillates at its resonant frequency no matter the input?

Comment: The tank circuit has a natural resonant frequency. The best way to describe it is to say that it always WANTS to resonate at that frequency when it is stimulated in any way. Similar to a string on a guitar. However you strum it, the note it plays is basically the same. If you drive a resonant circuit near its resonant frequency, the impedance will be at its lowest. As you move away from the resonant frequency, the impedance rises. In principal, if you have enough voltage available, you can drive a coil without a capacitor.

Comment: 1 MHz 5 kW. That would be a serious piece of equipment.

Comment: The skin depth is only 82 um in aluminum at 1 MHz.

Comment: electrogas' advice helped, but I'm not going to go that high in terms of power. I only have a 1.8 kW power source.